# Get Custom Validation Errors into BindingResult

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to remove repeating code from my Spring Controllers, specifically - removing the need to execute the validator.validate(form, bindingResult) from the start of many of my functions.

I have a few classes that have corresponding validator classes that implement Spring's validator interface. I have searched around to try and find an answer but I'm having trouble finding one that really matches this.

**Snippet of Person Form Class with annotated attributes**

```
public class Person {

   @Size(min=1, message="Name missing")
   private String name;
   @Size(min=1, message="Age missing")
   private String age;

   .... getters and setters etc.
```

**Person Validator Class**

```
@Component
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Person.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
} 

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        errors.reject("No sir!");
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have all the errors contained within the BindingResult, including the errors from the validator class. So that when I use the @Validated annotation my BindingResult is fully populated with all the errors from both the simple annotations and the custom validator.

**Desired Outcome**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)

public @ResponseBody String save(@Validated @RequestBody Person personForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) 
{

    bindingResult.getAllErrors(); <-- fully pop with annotation and custom validator errors
```

**Instead of:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)

public @ResponseBody String save(@Validated @RequestBody Person personForm, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) 
{

    personValidator.validate(person, bindingResult) <-- Populate bindingResult with customer validator errors, if any

    bindingResult.getAllErrors();
```

Has anyone got any neat examples they can share to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create `Constraint annotation` and implement `ConstraintValidator` instead of creating an unique validator for each class. By creating `Constraint` you can annotate a class or its class member fields and then leverage from `@Valid` and `BindingResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the validator to the databinder for multiple validators to work. In your code add an [`@InitBinder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) method and add the `PersonValidator` to the [`WebDataBinder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html).

```
@InitBinder("personForm")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder wdb) {
  wdb.addValidators(personValidator);
}
```

Will bind a validator to the `personForm` model object.

This will configure a global rule that this validator is applied to all bindings/conversions. If you want to limit this to a certain model you can specify the name of the model in the `@InitBinder`.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder wdb) {
  wdb.addValidators(personValidator);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this works now. What happens if my controller has two functions that accept to different form types? i.e. PersonForm and AnimalForm. I have just done this and it throws an error when I submit the animal form. After a bit of research it seems I might need to use the ModelAttribute instead of RequestBody in my method declaration. However, I am just submitting a JSON body and not a form - little unsure how to proceed! At least I'm 75% there now!

Comment: The `@InitBinder` takes a value of object types it applies to. So you can do `@InitBinder(PersonForm.class)` to limit the binding to this type.

Comment: can you pass more than one class to the InitBinder annotation? i.e. @InitBinder(PersonForm.class AnimalForm.class)?

Comment: Yes if you check the documentation you will see that it takes an array...

Comment: @InitBinder({"person"}) works fine but when I add "animal" to this string array and add my additional validator in the method I get an error "Invalid taget for validator". Is there a way to add multiple validators here?

Comment: All validators need to validate the same object and I doubt that `person` and `animal` refer to the same object type. So  you would need a seperate method for `animal`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190765/discussion-between-scoobyshnacks-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score -1):

As possible solution, you can define your own custom annotation and   **CustomConstraintValidator** that will implement interface `ConstraintValidator<A extends Annotation, T>.`
At the end BindingResult will contain either default validator and your custom validator errors.
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) is a good example.   If I understand your question correctly of course.