# Spring RabbitMQ: implement additional validations without custom annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-rabbit, hibernate-validator

In a Spring RabbitMQ project I am looking for a way to *programmatically* validate an object that has JSR303 annotations (like @NotNull, @Size, etc) while at the same time requires some custom validation logic. I would normally use a ConstraintValidator in combination with a custom Annotation, but the use of custom Annotations is **not an option** in this case.

I have the following (simplified) class, which is generated by Swagger and therefore cannot be edited:

```java
@ApiModel(description="User")
public class User {
    
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 6)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    ...
}
```

The additional validation logic is encapsulated in a validator:

```java
@Component
public class UserValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {

        return User.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) o;
        ...
        if(!valid) {
            errors.reject("some rejection");
        }
    }
}
```

The service in which the validation occurs:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeService {

    private final javax.validation.Validator validator; // might as well be org.springframework.validation.Validator if that works better
    
    public void someMethod(User user) {
    
        if (!validator.validate(user).isEmpty()) {
            // handle invalid user
        }
        
        ...
    }

}
```

However, the UserValidator is not being invoked. Is there some way to make Spring aware of the `UserValidator`? I have read some [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55353681/2148365) on using an [InitBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html), however as this is not a web MVC project but a rabbitMQ project I'm not sure whether this can be used.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your description how this is relevant to Spring AMQP, but if you want to use a validator on the listener method level, you should configure it respectively:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class Config implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {
    ...
    @Override
    public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
      registrar.setValidator(new MyValidator());
    }
}
```

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#rabbit-validation